# PHP foreach over CSV ignores first entry but print_r shows the entry is there

Tags: php, csv, iis, windows-server-2016

**Edit & Solved:**

Thanks to El_Vanja for the `var_dump` input, the file somehow had adiddional characters at the first line (not visible in notepad++), so I created a new file and it solved the problem. Case closed.

**Original Question**

We have an intranet-page where users can send a form to the HR. To get the user-infos we used to use activeX but since Edge is the new standard and activeX is no longer supported, we had to change this.

First users had to put in their E-Mail manually, but as you can guess, that was "too much tipping and stuff, not user-friendly!" for the average user, so I build a PHP-Script that gets the User-Info ($_SERVER['LOGON_USER']) and reads the E-Mails from a CSV-List, so that it is inserted automatically (Yes I know it's not best practice but the intranet-Server is no longer allowed to have access to the AD, so I had to work around it...).

This used to work without any problems, but since the last Windows-Server-Update I had one user that was not recognized, and it was the first user on the CSV-List (I can reproduce this with any user by putting it on the first entry of the CSV-List, to solve that I added a title line...).

Now my question is: Why and how is this possible? How can this script "ignore" the first entry?

My Code:

```
<?php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('Users.csv'));
$TempUser = explode("\\", $_SERVER['LOGON_USER'])[1];

foreach($csv As $Value)
{
    //$Value is an array since every entry in the CSV has Logon-name, Name and E-Mail
    if($Value[0] == $TempUser)
    {
        $name = $Value[1];
        $mail = $Value[2];
        break;
    }
}

if(isset($name))
{
    //insert User-Infos
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo $name;
    echo("User ".$_SERVER['LOGON_USER']." not found!");
}
?>
```

I also get an error since `echo $name;` is not asigned because the foreach loop does not "find" such an entry.

If I use `print_r($csv);` I can see that the entry is there, but in the loop the entry is not assigned. Every other entry will be assigned, just the first not. Also, if I run the foreach-loop and print every item it is also there.

This code does print out the first entry, also print_r does output the first line:

```
<?php
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('Users.csv'));

    foreach($csv As $Value)
    {
        //$Value is an array since every entry in the CSV has Logon-name, Name and E-Mail
        print_r($Value); 
        print("<br>");
    }
    
    print("<br>");
    print("<br>");
    
    print_r($csv);
?>
```

Before the Update this was not the case and everything worked normal. So any ideas what have changed? Is this normal? The problem is solved, but I am curious why this problem appeared or what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: I can't see anything immediate, my first thought was whether the update caused something to default to presuming there is a header line in the CSV file and ignore it, but that can't be the case if you can `print_r` and it is there. How did you solve the problem, does that give any clue to what changed?

Comment: Have you tried using `var_dump` on the value? `print_r` is nicer on the eyes, but doesn't have the extra data. I suspect there might be an invisible character there. Try `var_dump($Value[0])` and see if it has something extra that might cause it not to match.

Comment: @droopsnoot I inserted a headerline that can be ignored, so also the first user gets recognised. But as you said, that can't be, why should the first line be ignored..

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks for the tip, so I did a ```var_dump``` and the first line looks like that: ```{ [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "kurz" [1]=> string(4) "name" [2]=> string(4) "mail" }``` what is strange here to me is that the first entry says ```string(7)``` but it is only 4 chars long. So I checked the file in notepad++ with showing all the extra characters, but I can't see any. Next plan is to create the file new.

Comment: That confirms the invisible character. Might be something that Windows adds to the file (like a start-of-file mark or something), but I can't be sure, I'm not well-versed in the world of servers and filesystems. Creating a new file is a good test to see if this will happen again.

Comment: @El_Vanja I made a new file and guess what, I now works without the headerline! Thank you for your input :)

Comment: You're welcome... it seems then that the update might have added some info to files.

Comment: Couple of suggestions: look at the example in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and read the file like that. Getting rid of the first line is then a simple case of read and ignore, the second benefit is that should your csv file get BIG you wont blow memory limits reading all the file into an array

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the input, we have like 50-60 users so the file should not get too big, but good to keep in mind.

Comment: @El_Vanja maybe the three-character BOM (byte order mark) that sometimes gets in these files? Good spot.

Answer (score -1):

How did you edit your `Users.csv` file?

Maybe is the editor who put some unseen characters (like  [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) in the beginning of the file content.

You can use `echo strlen($Value[0]) . PHP_EOL;` to checkout it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the problem acctually was some invisible-characters at the csv, as El_Vanja suggessted, the ```var_dump``` showed that there were more characters than showed, so creating the csv new solved the problem.